# Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list Install Azure IoT Edge runtime on Linux

Tags: azure, iot, raspbian, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to install Azure IoT Edge runtime on Raspberry OS and I am always getting this error "Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list (type)" when I follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux). Please check the preceding image.

[image]

Anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: Did you have any problems with the moby-engine portion of the tutorial? I'm struggling with 'missing' kernel features on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @itstudes Are you sure that you followed the right commands? The Ubuntu 20.04 is in Tier 2 as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I ran the command as you suggested within your answer and that worked fine but then could not proceed further with installing moby-engine due to 'missing' kernel modules. When you mention that Ubuntu 20.04 is in Tier 2, does this mean that I don't need to install moby-engine? I can just install iotedge?

Comment: @itstudes No, you should install Debian 9 package, that is the suggestion mentioned in the doc for the Tier 2 OSes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ubuntu 20.04` comes under the [Tier 2 OSes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/support#tier-2), hence the Debian 9 packages from the [Azure IoT Edge releases repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iotedge/releases) should work out of the box with Ubuntu 20.04. See this [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/59910) for more info and follow the other steps mentioned in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux).

Tier 1:

[image]

Tier 2:

[image]

In the end, I installed `Rasbian OS` and followed the doc, you can see more info on [that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249180/one-of-the-iot-edge-module-is-in-backoff-state-raspberry-pi-4-with-raspbian-os/63299692#63299692).

Comment: It is not mentioned in the doc because it only list Tier 1 OSes for IoT Edge and Ubuntu 20.04 does is not currently Tier 1.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error while installing IOT Edge on Ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry PI 4,
I was changing the os version in this step:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/multiarch/prod.list > ./microsoft-prod.list
```

and I was getting the error in the next steps. This repo does no contain any builds for arm64.

things worked out for me when I left the tutorial command untouched this means 18.04.

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/multiarch/prod.list > ./microsoft-prod.list
```

and I was able to install IOT Edge.