# One of the IoT Edge Module is in Backoff state Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian OS

Tags: azure, docker, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I have developed a module and built the image for arm64v8 architecture as my Edge device is running in Raspberry Pi 4. I got the file deployment.arm64v8.json in the config folder correctly. But when I right-click on the device in Visual Studio Code and select Create Deployment for Single Device, the modules are getting added, but one of the modules is showing Backoff state. What could be the problem here, and was strictly following [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-develop-for-linux).

[image]

[image]

I also tried restarting the services.

[image]

**Device Information**

Host OS: Raspberry OS
Architecture: Arm64v8
Container OS: Linux containers

**Runtime Versions**

iotedged: iotedge 1.0.9.4
Docker/Moby [run docker version]:

[image]

**Update:**

I am trying to build arm32 image in my 64 bit Windows Dev Machine, I guess that is the reason why I am getting this issue. Now I have 3 options.

1. Install the 64 bit version of Raspberry OS from here
2. Set up a 32 bit virtual machine and use it as a dev machine and
   build 32 bit images
3. I already have a WSL running, maybe running the Visual Studio code
   solution there?

Could you please tell me what would be the better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were a couple of issues where I was doing wrong. First thing is that I was trying to build an arm64 image in my 64 bit Windows Dev Machine and then deploy the image to the arm32 `Raspbian OS`, which will never work. You can see the version and other details by running the below commands.

[image]

If it says `aarch64` then it is 64 bit. If it says `armv7l` then it is 32 bit. In my case, it is `arm71`. So now I had to build an `arm32` container images on my `64 bit Windows Host machine` and use it on my `Raspberry Pi 4`. According to [this doc](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/dotnetapp/README.md#build-an-image-for-arm32-and-arm64), it is definitely possible.

> You can build ARM32 and ARM64 images on x64 machines, but you will not
> be able to run them

Running was not my problem, as I just had to build the image and I will use it in my Raspberry Pi. To make it work, I had to change my `Dockerfile.arm32v7`, specifically the first line where we pull the base image.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim-arm32v7
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out ./

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash moduleuser
USER moduleuser

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SendTelemetry.dll"]
```

The "build-env" image should be the same architecture as the host OS, the final image should be the target OS architecture. Once I made the changes to the docker file, I changed the version in the `module.json` file inside my module folder so that the new image with a new tag will be added to the Container Registry when I use the option `Build and Push IoT Edge Solution` after right-clicking `deployment.template.json`, and then I used `Create Deployment for Single Device` option after right-clicking on the device name in Visual Studio Code. And then when I monitor the device (Start Monitoring Built-in Event Endpoint option), I am getting this output.

[image]

Support with Microsoft was really cool with this issue. They really helped me to solve this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/3353) that I had posted.

Comment: I got caught up with 64 vs 32 to because of https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/specifications/ which is 64 v8 - I forgot that when selecting the OS in the imager it was 32 bit.